# Only safe call allowed error when EditText is used to send string to firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin-null-safety

I am new to Firebase. I have made a simple project which sends user strings to Realtime Database in Firebase. For input, I have used the EditText view. Here is my main activity. username is the id of EditText View

```
package com.example.firebase
import...

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.Remote.setOnClickListener {


            val name = binding.username.text.toString() //Error on this line
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
            val User = User(name)
            database.child(name).setValue(User).addOnSuccessListener {
                binding.username.text.clear() //And This Line
                Toast.makeText(this,"Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
```

After Building following error is shown on the commented line of code:

> Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type EditText.

It works fine if I direct enter a string instead of using EditText View. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `username` EditText object is null. So there are two ways in which you solve this problem:

1. Use safe call (?.)

   ```
    val name = binding.username?.text.toString()
    //
   ```
2. Use a non-null asserted (!!.)

   ```
    val name = binding.username!!.text.toString()
    //
   ```

See more info inside the Kotlin documentation regarding [null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html).

Comment: I don't think it's this - the error is complaining about the `EditText` reference itself being nullable, so you have to do `binding.username?.text` to make a safe call on it. Plus it's ok to call `toString()` on *null* anyway!

Comment: @cactustictacs Yes u r correct, Build was successful and also string was written to database, I have to make following changes
i) val name = binding.username.text.toString() to val name = binding.username?.text.toString()
ii) binding.username.text.clear() to binding.username!!.text.clear()

Comment: @cactustictacs You're right, `?` added on the wrong object. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have different versions of that layout file (e.g. portrait/landscape, small screen, different API level etc)? Check you have an `EditText` with an ID of `username` in all of them - if it's missing from some variations, the generated binding class makes that property nullable, since it might not be present (depending on which version of the layout file was inflated)